# Lucene.net UpdateDocument() - adjust boost

Tags: c#, boost, lucene.net

I need to increase the boost of documents as part of an update operation - but I need to add to a documents existing boost, if any.

Is there any way to  achieve this?

The docs say about `document.Boost`:

> Note that once a document is indexed this value is no
>   longer available from the index. At search time, for retrieved documents, this method always returns
>   1. This however does not mean that the boost value set at indexing time was
>   ignored - it was just combined with other indexing time factors and stored
>   elsewhere, for better indexing and search performance. (For more information
>   see the "norm(t,d)" part of the scoring formula in Lucene.Net.Search.Similarity.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a custom weight/boost score?  Not sure if this would help you, but having custom weight scores is a lot easier to manage.